# Add class to nth attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently add an attribute to the HTML element like shown below. I'm trying to add a class to nth element. For example `.project`'s with `data-project-id` of 1, 4, 7... would add class `.project-group-1` and 2, 5, 8... would add class `.project-group-2` etc...

```
<a class="project" data-project-id="1" href="#">Project</a>
<a class="project" data-project-id="2" href="#">Project</a>
<a class="project" data-project-id="3" href="#">Project</a>
```

Is there any jQuery helpers that make this possible?

Comment: [`:nth-child` selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and [`:nth-of-type` selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)

Comment: Or, loop through all `.project` elements and test the value of `.data('project-id')%3`

Comment: nth-child won't help if order/distribution is not linear. you will need to collect all the apropos data-project-ids, then filter down to the ones whose attrib values modulo minus the base is 0, then addClass() to those remaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.project').each(function() {
        var groups = 3;
        var group = parseInt($(this).data('project-id')) % groups;
        $(this).addClass('project-group-' + (group == 0 ? groups : group));
    });
});
```

You can check it out in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z3u9bmea/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var count =1;
    $( ".project" ).each(function() {
        var project_id = $(this).attr("data-project-id");
        if(project_id != "undefined"){

            if(count == 1) {
              $(this).addClass("project-group-"+project_id);                
            }

            count++;
            if(count == 3)
                count = 1;            
        }
    });
});
```

Look at [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haiderali/gv9pct29/) example

Comment: This doesn't work as some of the elements can be randomly placed in the DOM tree.

Comment: @AleksiTappura do you want to add class on nth element which have already class project or which have data-project-id also ....  ?

Comment: @AleksiTappura don't loop because that would be very bad ..... Since Jquery is there no need of loop

Comment: I might've shaped my question badly, but what I'm trying to achieve is to add certain class to for example every third data-project-id element. So projects with data-project-id="1", data-project-id="4" and data-project-id="7" for example would add class ".project-group-1".

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums = ["1","4","7"];
for( i in nums){
     $("a[data-project-id=" + nums[i] + "]").addClass("project-group-" + nums[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(".project").addClass(function () {
    var groupId = this.dataset.projectId % 3 == 0 ? 3 : this.dataset.projectId % 3;
    return "project-group-" + groupId;
});
```

```css
.project-group-1 {
    background: red;
}
.project-group-2 {
    background: blue;
}
.project-group-3 {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="project" data-project-id="1" href="#">Project</a>
<a class="project" data-project-id="2" href="#">Project</a>
<a class="project" data-project-id="3" href="#">Project</a>
<a class="project" data-project-id="4" href="#">Project</a>
<a class="project" data-project-id="5" href="#">Project</a>
<a class="project" data-project-id="6" href="#">Project</a>
<a class="project" data-project-id="7" href="#">Project</a>
<a class="project" data-project-id="8" href="#">Project</a>
<a class="project" data-project-id="9" href="#">Project</a>
```